# Override close button

Tags: xna, windows

How can I override the close button near minimize/maximize in such a way that the application doesn't automatically close. I want it to show an exit screen or something like this, so I would like to be able to delay the close and display something on the screen when I press the red close button. At first I thought that I should override the OnExiting() method, but I couldn't get it working. This is my first attempt at creating a fully functional game, so I have no previous experience in game development nor with XNA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described [on the XNA Community Forum](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/44962/268306.aspx#268306), you can get the host `Form` and listen to the `FormClosing` event, which allows you to cancel the event. The example code from the community form reads:

```
protected override void LoadContent() 
{ 
    Form f = Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle) as Form; 
    if (f != null) 
    { 
        f.FormClosing += f_FormClosing; 
    } 
    base.LoadContent(); 
} 

void f_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No) 
        e.Cancel = true; 
}
```

Using that as a template, you should be able to come up with a method for bringing up an in-game dialog. You'll likely need to introduce a variable that indicates whether the user really wants to quit or not. For example:

```
bool userReallyWantsToQuit = false;

void f_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!userReallyWantsToQuit)
    {
        displayExitMessage();    // Show the user something useful
        e.Cancel = true; 
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if(keyboard.keyDown[Esc])    // Complete pseudocode. This will be your true exit condition
    {
         userReallyWantsToQuit = true;
         Exit();
    }
}
```